# Python - Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Im very new to programming and am looking for a bit of help improving a piece of code. I've gotten the desired outcome for my tutorial work, but its not done in a great way.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth

    def get_details(self):
        return(f"Name: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}\nDate of Birth: {self.date_of_birth}")



class Worker:
    def__init__(self, tax_file_number, super_number):
        self.tax_file_number = tax_file_number
        self.super_number = super_number

    def get_info(self):
        return(f"TFN: {self.tax_file_number}\nSuper: {self.super_number}")


class Employee(Person, Worker):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, tax_file_number, super_number, employee_id, position):
        Person.__init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
        Worker.__init__(self, tax_file_number, super_number)
        self.employee_id = employee_id
        self.position = position

    def get_info(self):
        return(f"Employee ID: {self.employee_id}\nPosition: {self.position}")
        
    def get_details(self):
        person = (Person.get_details(self)) + "\n" + (Employee.get_info(self)) + "\n" + (Worker.get_info(self))
        return person


p = Person("Kim", "White", "12/08/2020")
print(p.get_details())
print()
w = Worker(4556655, 567)
print(w.get_info())
print()
e = Employee('Kim', 'White', '12/08/2020', 4556655, 567, 1121, 'Developer')
print(e.get_details())
```

The issue for me is Employee Class with the multiple inheritance,
Do I really need to initialize all the attributes like that? I thought using inheritance it would take it from the other classes,
but this is how I managed to get it to work.

I was trying to make it so it would be more like,

```
class Employee(Person, Worker):
    def init(self, employee_id, position):
        self.employee_id = employee_id
        self.position = position
        #*Line of code to make it so the rest of the attributes come in here #
```

Comment: your current code is a pain to read, can you please format it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Using `super()` in all three classes, you can ensure that each initializer is called in the correct order, and only needs to handles its own new attributes explicitly.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth

    def get_details(self):
        return(f"Name: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}\nDate of Birth: {self.date_of_birth}")


class Worker:
    def__init__(self, tax_file_number, super_number, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tax_file_number = tax_file_number
        self.super_number = super_number

    def get_info(self):
        return(f"TFN: {self.tax_file_number}\nSuper: {self.super_number}")


class Employee(Person, Worker):
    def __init__(self, employee_id, position, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.employee_id = employee_id
        self.position = position

    def get_info(self):
        return(f"Employee ID: {self.employee_id}\nPosition: {self.position}")
        
    def get_details(self):
        person = (Person.get_details(self)) + "\n" + (Employee.get_info(self)) + "\n" + (Worker.get_info(self))
        return person


e = Employee(first_name='Kim', last_name='White', date_of_birth='12/08/2020', tax_file_number=4556655, super_number=567, employee_id=1121, position='Developer')
```

Each `__init__` method only needs to name the attributes that it introduces; any other keyword arguments are passed on to a parent class. Eventually, one of the calls to `super().__init__` should invoke `object.__init__`, by which time you should have "consumed" all of the keyword arguments and `kwargs` should be empty.

For more information about using `super` correctly to support multiple inheritance, see [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

---

You can probably also define `get_details()` in each class similarly, returning `super().get_details + "\n" + [my details here]`.